# Multilingual Dropdowns from DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, multilingual

I have a multilingual MVC3 site, well it would be multilingual if the dropdowns were in more than one language.... so my question is what's the best approach for storing multilingual database values? Or has anyone tried translating on the fly using an api?

Thanks for any help in advance.